# How to add firebase to my bash profile?

Tags: firebase, path, bash, firebase-tools

I have been having trouble installing firebase command line tools. I am following the guide at: https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/command-line-tool.html.  I have run the initial command into my terminal: `npm install -g firebase-tools`. Once I run: `firebase init` in the root of my directory, I get the following error:

`-bash: firebase: command not found`

I have looked at guides how to manually modify my bash profile, but can not figure out how to do so... Shouldn't my bash .bash_profile automatically get modified when I run a global command?? Any help would be appreciated. I just need my firebase commands to work in the terminal, and why the global command won't register in my bash profile?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `npm install -g firebase` it tries to install the firebase library and associated binaries into a system-wide location.  You can determine where this location is by running `npm prefix -g`.  In order for the `firebase` binary to be available to your bash session, the bin directory inside your global npm prefix must be on your path.

In Bash, an easy way to add a directory to your PATH is by modifying the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.  Appending a line like so will add the global npm bin directory to your current PATH:

`PATH="$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH"`

Once you have modified your PATH variable either open a new terminal session or run `export PATH="$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH"` for the change to immediately take effect.

If `~/.bashrc` is not being sourced on your machine, an easy fix is adding the following line to your `~/.bash_profile` file:

`source "$HOME/.bashrc"`

Comment: If my terminal states ~/.bashrc does not exist, should I create a blank file and add PATH="$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" to it? I have already added 'source "$HOME/.bashrc" ' to my bash profile, but that alone is not doing much

Comment: Yup, add a new file called `.bashrc` with that line in it.  Then start a new terminal session.